# Is it possible to apply a nofollow to hidden modal content (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, seo

**Question:** I have tons of disclaimer copy that is part of a modal and sits as a display:none in the body until a button is clicked. I don't want the copy in the modal indexed by bots, but I cant throw a nofollow in the header as I want the rest of the copy on the page indexed. Is there a way to assign a relatively universal nofollow to a div or paragraph tag that contains the content I want to tell search engines to ignore?

**Partial Solution:** I see for googlebot, you can wrap the content in google bot tags to delineate where indexing is supposed to be disabled.

```
 <!--googleoff: index-->Some content that wont get indexed by Google<!--googleon: index-->
```

But, I need something that will also work with Bing and Yahoo.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way to stop search engines indexing **part** of a page is the googleon/googleoff solution (that you've already mentioned in your question).

It sounds like you require the "googleoff: index" tag.

```
<!--googleoff: index-->

<p>The content you don't want to be indexed.</p>

<!--googleon: index>
```

Here's a link to a [detailed blog post on how to use the on/off tags](https://perishablepress.com/tell-google-to-not-index-certain-parts-of-your-page/).

There isn't a Yahoo or Bing alternative tag to do this. However, in my experience, both Yahoo and Bing appear to be following the tag instructions and not indexing the content.

Here's [one blog post that confirms this](http://www.webdistortion.com/2013/10/08/undocumented-seo-google-on-off-tags/) (you'll be able to find others).

Hope this helps.